# Cannot update records using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

Assuming that i have two records with following fields in database

1 A, A, A;
2 B, B, B;

The combination of all fields should be unique. Let's say i am trying to do perform an update to make my records looks like this:

1 B, B, B;
2 A, A, A;

I am using Session.saveOrUpdate(entity) method to do this, but commit fails, basically because   i am trying to update an entity 1 with values, that are representing existing entity 2 and unique constraint blocks this update.

How to avoid this situation and do update correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

- Start a session and a transaction
- Load your two records
- Update the values of these records
- Commit the transaction

saveOrUpdate doesn't have to be used in that scenario because you're only updating existing records.

Comment: Awesome, but what if there are 10000 records that was loaded by 7000 users at a time? Is there any other way?

Comment: If you have that many concurrent update you need to carefully choose your locking strategy. Options are pessimistic locking (the DB locks the rows), optimistic locking (the update fails if another user has updated the same row), no locking (last commit wins),...